# adding field to the combo box in assest depreciation profile form

Tags: dynamics-ax-2012, axapta

i am new to ax2012. I have a doubt in asset depreciation profile form.There is combo box called period frequency in that, i need to add  a field called monthly.  Can any one help me out ?
 I have tried out by creating base enum for monthly filed but i didn't get the output required.

Comment: Could you give further information about where the form asset depreciation profile can be found?

Comment: Form "Asset depreciation profile" can be found under "Fixed assets>Setup>Depreciation>Depreciation profiles".

Answer (score 1):

This field is an Enum of type `AssetAccrualFiscal`, therefore you need to add a monthly element to this `AssetAccrualFiscal` in the AOT.

Beware however, the field is controlled by an edit method, and changing the field triggers some business logic.

This can be found in the table method `accrualFiscal()` on the table `AssetDepreciationProfile`. You may need to decide which part of the existing logic needs to consider your new enum element when it is selected.

Comment: Tricky, depending on field depreciation year, two different enums are shown in period frequency, one with a "monthly" element (AssetAccrualCalendar), the other without (AssetAccrualFiscal). Since user3172646 is missing the element, he probably uses fiscal depreciation year, which makes your answer correct.

Answer (score 0):

See my comment, but basically you need to find out which base enum the combo box uses (supposing it is an enum combo box) and add a new element "monthly" to that enum.

If it is a standard enum, please leave a gap between the last enum element index and the index of your new element. This leaves room for new elements from Microsoft and enables easier upgrades.

---

Did some digging, in AX 2012 R2 there already is an element "monthly" for the period frequency combo box. Please take a look at enum "AssetAccrualCalendar" and method "accrualCalendar" on table AssetDepreciationProfile.